# Update an image control as soon as a file is selected in File Upload control in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ajax, file-upload, updatepanel

I have an image control and a file upload control in .NET 2.0 (VS.NET 2008) form. As soon as user selects an image file in the file upload control,  i want the image to appear in the image control of the form. What would be the way to do this ?

(The only event File Upload seems to support is 'OnChange' and i don't know enough javascript to update Image1.URL based on content of FileUpload).

Thanks,
Chak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upload `Asynchronously` , and you could try AJAX `AsyncFileUpload` and this is what you are looking...
http://asp.net-informations.com/ajax/ajax-AsyncFileUpload.htm

Comment: I am yet to try this out, but this seems close to what i need.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good example:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/AJAXUpload.aspx

this is a good starting point too:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10204276/how-to-display-image-when-upload-image.aspx

or here:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10236947/image-upload-and-display.aspx

**updated**

```
  protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strExtn;
        string strpostedfile;

        strpostedfile = fileuploading.PostedFile.FileName;
        strExtn = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(strpostedfile);
        strExtn = strExtn.ToLower();

        string strEx = Path.GetExtension(fileuploading.PostedFile.FileName).ToLower();
        String filename = Path.GetFileName(fileuploading.FileName);
        filename = filename.Remove(filename.Length - strEx.Length);

        fileuploading.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Photos/") + filename);
        uploadImage.ImageUrl = "~/Photos/" + filename;

    }
```

Page:

```
  <asp:FileUpload ID="fileuploading" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" onclick="Button4_Click" Text="Button" />
<br />
<asp:Image ID="uploadImage" runat="server" />
```

Comment: This example needs an additional button control is it not ? I wanted to avoid an extra button click.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a kind of preview? You can only show the image to the user after the file has been uploaded. I'm pretty sure the user has to actively do so (otherwise you could try to read the entire filesystem from the browser)

Comment: I don't want preview. I want image to appear in image control on  selection of file in file upload control.

Comment: That is before the user clicks "upload"? In my view that is a preview and this is not possible.